# Not iterable Error with constraints in minimize from scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, restriction

I just started studying optimization with Python and I am facing an issue.
I have a problem where I want to minimize my objective function (obj_fun) using minimize from scipy.optimize.
I will share an example:

```
import numpy as np

def analysis(A):
    N = []
    for i in A:
        N.append(i*3)
    return N

def cons(A):
    N = analysis(A)
    C = []
    for i in len(N):
        if N[i] < 2:
            C.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0]*N[i]})
        else:
            C.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0]-N[i]})
    return C

def obj_fun(A):
    """Objective function returns the weight of the structure"""
    w=  0.5*[1*A[0]+2*A[1]+3*A[2]]
    return w

# Initial values
A0 = np.array([0.001 for i in range(0, 3)])

N = analysis(A0)

##  Optimization

bnds = [(1e-6, None) for i in range(len(A0))]

from scipy.optimize import minimize
sol = minimize(obj_fun, x0=A0, method='trust-constr', bounds=bnds, 
constraints=cons)
print(sol)
```

The whole error I get is:
runfile('C:/Users/Myc/Documents/Python Scripts/example stack.py', wdir='C:/Users/Myc/Documents/Python Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Myc\Documents\Python Scripts\example stack.py", line 40, in 
sol = minimize(obj_fun, x0=A0, method='trust-constr', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)

File "C:\Users\Myc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_minimize.py", line 605, in minimize
constraints = standardize_constraints(constraints, x0, meth)

File "C:\Users\Myc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_minimize.py", line 825, in standardize_constraints
constraints = list(constraints)  # ensure it's a mutable sequence

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

I know the main problem is how i define the constraints and I could replace constraints=cons for constraints = Cons1 if i define Cons1 = rest(A0) before the optimization.
However that wouldn't help me because I need the function trus_analysis to be executed on every iteration of the optimization in order to update the parameters N for the restrictions.
How can I define the constraints?

Comment: Don't just summarize the error!  Show whole thing.  While you are at it show `C`, and tell us what `minimize` expects from the `constraints` parameter.  No summaries or interpretations.

Comment: When I test your code it runs.

Comment: As instructed, I posted the whole script. Thanks for your attention in advance, @hpaulj

Comment: I didn't ask for the whole script.  Just the whole error.  This looks like a whole new problem

Comment: I just changed the script for a simpler example and posted the whole error.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to *call* the function `cons`; the argument to `minimize` should be `constraints=cons(A0)`.  (You will encounter more bugs after you fix that, but that should fix the issue reported in the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original script:

```
def obj_fun(A):
    return 7*A[0]+ 3*A[1]+ 7*A[2]

def analysis(A):
    N = []
    for i in A:
        N.append(i*3)
    return N

def cons(A):
    n = analysis(A)
    C = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if n[i] < 4:
            C.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[i]**2 / n[i]})
        else:
            C.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[i] - n[i]})
    return C


A0 = [1,2,3]
C = cons(A0)
bnds = [(1e-6, None) for i in range(len(A0))]

from scipy.optimize import minimize
sol = minimize(obj_fun, x0=A0, method='trust-constr', bounds=bnds, constraints=C)
print(sol)
```

runs with:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_hessian_update_strategy.py:182: UserWarning: delta_grad == 0.0. Check if the approximated function is linear. If the function is linear better results can be obtained by defining the Hessian as zero instead of using quasi-Newton approximations.
  warn('delta_grad == 0.0. Check if the approximated '
 barrier_parameter: 0.00016000000000000007
 barrier_tolerance: 0.00016000000000000007
          cg_niter: 15
      cg_stop_cond: 1
            constr: [array([9.00009143]), array([4.57149698e-05]), array([4.57149698e-05]), array([2.38571416e-05, 5.43334162e-05, 9.00004571e+00])]
       constr_nfev: [40, 40, 40, 0]
       constr_nhev: [0, 0, 0, 0]
       constr_njev: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    constr_penalty: 1.0
  constr_violation: 0.0
    execution_time: 0.0873115062713623
               fun: 63.00065000502843
              grad: array([7.        , 3.        , 6.99999999])
               jac: [array([[0.        , 0.        , 2.00001017]]), array([[0., 0., 1.]]), array([[0., 0., 1.]]), array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])]
   lagrangian_grad: array([1.77635684e-15, 1.55431223e-14, 5.67948534e-14])
           message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
            method: 'tr_interior_point'
              nfev: 40
              nhev: 0
               nit: 14
             niter: 14
              njev: 10
        optimality: 5.679485337974424e-14
            status: 1
           success: True
         tr_radius: 18734.614693588483
                 v: [array([-1.77775972e-05]), array([-3.49997333]), array([-3.49997333]), array([-7.00000000e+00, -3.00000000e+00, -1.77776895e-05])]
                 x: array([2.38571416e-05, 5.43334162e-05, 9.00004571e+00])
```

Here

```
In [36]: C
Out[36]: 
[{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': <function __main__.cons.<locals>.<lambda>(x)>},
 {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': <function __main__.cons.<locals>.<lambda>(x)>},
 {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': <function __main__.cons.<locals>.<lambda>(x)>}]
```

`A0` is used the create the 3 constraint functions.

The `analysis` function just multiplies `A` by 3.

```
In [38]: analysis(A0)
Out[38]: [3, 6, 9]
In [39]: A0
Out[39]: [1, 2, 3]
In [40]: analysis(A0)
Out[40]: [3, 6, 9]
In [41]: np.array(A0)*3
Out[41]: array([3, 6, 9])
```

In the latest `cons` you dropped the `range`, and use `cons` directly rather than `cons(A0)`.  The `constraints` parameter is supposed to be a **list** of  `dict`, as shown in `C`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
In the original script I am working, the analysis function call other complex functions to return the parameter N. In the example I just multiplied by 3 in a way of simplifying things.
The problem is that if I use `C = cons(A0)` as the constraint, the analysis function is not called to update the list of constraints at each iteration of the optimization.
Do you know how can I deal with this problem or if that is even possible?
Am I am not facing the problem in the right direction.

Comment: In this simple `cons`, `x` is the current state, while `n` is based on the initial value.  It doesn't make sense for `n` to depend on `x` (`A`) does it?  In any case, `minimize` expects `constraints` to be a list of dicts like `C`.  You can't give it a function to evaluate fresh each time.

Comment: The functions in the constraints don't have to be `lambdas`.  They can be regular `def` functions, with more expressive power.